# Is this a Dictionary in an older Python version?

Tags: python

I'm new to Python and am reading a book that came out in 2009 and so uses Python 2.5 syntax. It does the following:

```
_fields_ = [
    ("cb", DWORD),
    ("lpReserved", LPTSTR),
    ...
]
```

To me it looks like a list of tuples, but at the same time it feels like a Map/Dictionary. Was this the older syntax?

Comment: it's worth noting that `dict(_fields)` would return the dictionary that is constructed in the obvious way.

Comment: If you turned it into a dict you'd lose the ordering present in the list-of-tuples version, which might be significant. (Python gets an standardised ordered map datatype in 3.2, with `collections.OrderedDict`.)

Comment: @bobince: good to mention the detail of the dictionary being unordered.  `collections.OrderedDict` is in python 2.7 as well.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It's perfectly good, current syntax, and expresses a list of pairs (two-item tuples).  If you need a dict (and have no problem with duplicate keys;-), `dict(_fields_)` will make you one (much like `somedict.items()` makes you a list of pairs from a dict -- `list(somedict.items())` if you're in Python 3 but insist on getting a list rather than just a view/iterator, btw;-).

Answer (score 4):

No, this was always a list of tuples.  That looks like a datatype "mapping" for the purposes of ctypes, but it's just a list, not a real map.

Answer (score 3):

No, that's just a list of tuples. Dictionaries in Python have always used the `{}` notation.